# How loop through array in jQuery and append the values in the array inside an li

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements

I have a simple array in jQuery with numbers. The numbers 3, 6, 9, 12, 15 represent a specific location in an unordered list that I want to Insert an html div. So after the 3, 6 , 9, etc li I want to insert a div.  This is my jQuery. In my code it seems to only insert the div after the 15th li. How do I insert the div at each specific location and not just the last one?

```
    var row = [3, 6, 9, 12, 15];

    var emptyDiv= $('<div></div>');

    jQuery.each(row, function(i, val){
        $(emptyDiv).insertAfter('ul#state-list li:nth-child(' + val + ')');
    });
```

Comment: You are only creating one div, so it can only be in one place at a time. Perhaps you wanted to create multiple divs?

Comment: this will create invalid markup.. If  you really want to do it then try moving `var emptyDiv= $('<div></div>');` to inside the each loop

Comment: @Sushanth-- What would be invalid?

Comment: @PaulS. That's not how `insertAfter` works - read the docs and look at the examples: http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/

Comment: You don't need to use `$(emptyDiv)` - just use `emptyDiv` - it's already a jQuery object and has access to jQuery methods like `insertAfter`

Comment: @Ian .. The OP will have a mix of `li` and `div` as child elements in `ul` . Don't you think that is invalid ? That is if he is using `insertAfter`

Comment: @Sushanth-- You're right! I wasn't paying attention to the actual elements. I was just wondering because that wasn't immediately obvious to me :( Good catch

Comment: @Ian.. understandable after a tiring day :)

Comment: @Ian `insertAfter` **does not** create new nodes; http://jsfiddle.net/sBs8W/

Comment: @PaulS. Example from jQuery docs: http://jsfiddle.net/LEhBs/

Comment: @PaulS... That is not the problem .. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/sBs8W/1/ .. If you create a new span and reference it to a variable. On subsequent selections it does not create a new element as the variable holds the same reference.. So you are to reference the variable again

Comment: @PaulS. I think I see my problem. Nevermind

Comment: Guys thank you for all of the great input. My markup is invalid I didn't catch it myself. I did get my code to work. I just had to place my emptyDiv inside my loop...DUH lol ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var row = [3, 6, 9, 12, 15];
jQuery.each(row, function(i, val) {
    $('<div>').insertAfter('ul#state-list li:nth-child(' + val + ')');
});
```

Comment: Thank you this was a big help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.clone()`.

The .clone() method creates a copy of the matched elements.

In your case instead of create a empty div for each row, you were just inserting (moving) the div in the rows. So in the first loop the div was in row 3, in the second loop the div was in row 6, and so on, until reach the row 15.

So with .clone() method you insert a **copy** of the div, and each row will have a copy of the div.

```
var row = [3, 6, 9, 12, 15];

var emptyDiv= $('<div></div>');

jQuery.each(row, function(i, val){
    emptyDiv.clone().insertAfter('ul#state-list li:nth-child(' + val + ')');
});
```

More info about .clone() method at : http://api.jquery.com/clone/